# Get unique id at the same time get the sum of value for each id

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get all unique ID from table and get sum of value from value_1 to value_640 for each unique ID.
structure of the table:

```
ID_col_1  Value_1  ID_col_2  Value_2  ID_col3  Value_3  ....  ID_col_640  Value_640        
10001       2       10007      1       10004      1             10010        1        
10003       3       10001      3       10005      0             10020        2        
10005       4       10006      4       10011      0             10001        8        
10001       10      10009      8       10007      2             10017        3        
10009       0       10004      1       10001      3             10018        10        
10002       2       10001      0       10008      4             10009        7
```

I want to Result as below example:
Exp:

```
 10001=2+1+3+0+3....+8
 10002=...
 10003=...
 10004=...
 10005=...
 ...
 10020=...
```

Is there any way to done this with mysql?

Comment: This is pretty much a basic `group by` query with `sum()`.  Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: I don't think it's quite as simple as a plain `group by` - it looks like the OP wants to pull together the data from 640 separate column pairs to one output column pair.

Comment: I tried group by query, if i only group it by ID_Col_1, then i have lost some id in other columns which is not appered in ID_Col_1.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Yes, you are right, that is what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this (I suggest generating the full expression programatically):

```
select id, sum(val) from
    (
    select ID_col_1 as id, Value_1 as val from tbl
    union
    select ID_col_2 as id, Value_2 as val from tbl
    ...
    union
    select ID_col_640 as id, Value_640 as val from tbl
    )
group by id
```

No promise that performance will be good :)

Depending on how big the data set is and how often you need to run this (once or repeatedly), you may want to store the union in a temporary table or a permanent table and then run the summarization against that.

If you need to do this frequently, you may also want to consider either changing your table schema or just storing a parallel normalized copy.

Comment: Thank you so much,it is very helpful which you mentioned, i just customized it as : 
`select id, sum(val) from 
(
select ID_col_1 as id , sum(value_1) as val from tb1 group by ID_col_1
union
select ID_col_2 as id , sum(value_2) as val from tb1 group by ID_col_2
...
union
select ID_col_640 as id , sum(value_640) as val from tb1 group by ID_col_640
)
group by id;
`

Comment: I just noticed that we should use `union all` to get expected result in place of `union`.